# jQuery load html file into <div>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I wanted to know how I can use an html file and use it to replace the space inside a

I know you can do it with jquery but for some reason it isn't working out for me.
I have:

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
    $('#nav li a').click(function(){  
        var toLoad = $(this).attr('href');  
        $('#main').hide('fast',loadContent);   
        function loadContent() {  
            $('#main').load(toLoad);  
        }  
        return false; 
    });  
});
```

So whenever I click a link from my navbar it should edit the #main div and bring up the corresponding html file to replace the div with. For some reason it just leaves it blank.

Comment: You load things into `main`, but don't show it again!

Comment: `$('#main').show();` might help after the `load` call...

Comment: Please use Firebug or similar inspector tool next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this line

```
 $('#main').hide('fast',loadContent);
```

It is hiding the div where you are loading the content. If you show that div again, you can see the content on div. So

```
 Change 

 $('#main').load(toLoad);

 to 

 $('#main').load(toLoad).show();
```

Comment: Can you add some comments on why you suggest this option? What is wrong with the OP question?

Comment: $('#main').hide('fast',loadContent); //Statement hiding the div#main

Comment: Add it to your answer, not on the comments. Click on the `edit` link right under your answer and add all you need to clarify your answer

Answer (score 0):

You may try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('#nav li a').click(function(e){  
        e.preventDefault();
        var toLoad = $(this).attr('href');
        $('#main').hide('fast', function(){  
            $('#main').load(toLoad, function(){
                $('#main').show('fast');
            });  
        });
    });
});
```

`$('#main').hide('fast',loadContent);` is hiding the `div` so need to show it again so I've used this `$('#main').show('fast');` in load's callback function.